# What kind of fires are "controlled by a creature?"

Tags: dnd-4e

The oh so delicious Control Flame manipulates "non-living fire ... that is not controlled by a creature."

Do zones, non-sustained zones, environmental effects, and/or torches count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd treat the "controlled by a creature" part as any instance of a flame that is either:

- part of the equipment of a creature (including magical and non-magical torches);
- part of a Zone, Aura or Conjuration power or trait a creature activated (e.g.: a [Flaming Sphere](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1435)<sup>DDI</sup>);
- part of a power's sustainable effect or attack originated from a creature (e.g.: the [Control Flame](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=16244)<sup>DDI</sup> itself).

I'd exclude flames that:

- have been created by any instantaneous, non-sustainable power or effect, even if it deals ongoing fire damage.

E.g.: one of the [Kobold Slinger](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=302)<sup>DDI</sup>'s special ammunition sets the target on fire. Even if the target's equipment could be enveloped in flame, I don't think we could consider it as "part of the equipment". Also, the slinger has no more control on the flame (the kobold cannot sustain it).

Answer (score 0):

The way I would read this: Any fire is a viable target, as long as its manipulation would not conflict with the intent of the caster of the source of the fire.

If the torch is a normal torch, then fine. If the torch is a magical torch, you can't control it. Same with a Zone, or non-sustained zones. You can't use this power to negate the zone.